# python чтение файла в сети

Tags: python, файлы

Есть файл, который располагается на шаре в сети \Swift\dhcp$\clients.txt , подскажите  как прочитать его по сети.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
with open('//Swift/dhcp$/clients.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Попробовал, отображается ошибка - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/mac6/txt.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open('//Swift/dhcp$/clients.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//Swift/dhcp$/clients.txt' , может файл не видит из - за авторизации?

Comment: Хм, а если развернуть слеши и добавить r перед строкой, вот так ->r'\\Swift\dhcp$\clients.txt' ?

Хотя если используется авторизация и сеть UNC. То стоит копать в сторону NET USE.

Comment: @Exord благодарю за ответы, вопрос решен, остановился на использовании библиотеки SambaClient.